# Change of limits in integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there any way to change the limits of a 3-D function without sketching its graph? I mean, can I obtain the same results algebraically for 3-D? 
For example $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{-\sqrt{4-2x}}^{\sqrt{4-2x}}f(x,y,z) dy dz dx$$ to $$\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}f(x,y,z) dz dx dy$$ or $$\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}f(x,y,z) dx dz dy$$ and I need to obtain the limits. Is there any algebraic method?

Comment: I think you are almost always better off sketching the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^2\int_0^x\int_{-\sqrt{4-2x}}^{\sqrt{4-2x}}f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Note that $0\le x\le2$, $0\le z\le x$, and $2x+y^2\le4$, so one change of order would be
$$
\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{2-y^2/2}\int_z^{2-y^2/2}f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z \,\mathrm{d}y
$$
another would be
$$
\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{2-y^2/2}\int_0^xf(x,y,z)\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: So it is all about working with the limits as inequalities.

Comment: @Artemisia: it is about covering the same region in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and that region is defined by these inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

You would just change the limits as per the order of the differentials on the right side.

$$\int_{-\sqrt{4-2x}}^{\sqrt{4-2x}}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y,z) dz dx dy$$

That would not work however because the outermost limits of integration rely on $x$ and $x$ is integrated in an inner integral.

$$\int_{-\sqrt{4-2x}}^{\sqrt{4-2x}}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{2}f(x,y,z) dx dz dy$$

Once again, this will not work because of the above reason.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how the limits need to be altered to change the order of integration. They seem to know that simply blindly changing order is not valid.